# Select the valued record or show the empty valued record : mySQL

Tags: mysql

**Case scenario**: A warehouse has multiple locations and each location has a bin-Cart-Number. When a new shipment arrives if the product has the same bin-Cart-Number as in a warehouse location record then in the location drop-down only that location shows if there is no such bin-Cart-Number in the warehouse then all the available locations appear in the drop-down (means where bin-Cart-Number is null or empty).

```
SELECT 
    l.id, l.c_locationNumber
FROM
    location l
        JOIN
    shipmentParts sp ON sp.bin - Cart - Number = l.bin - Cart - Number
WHERE
    l.bin - Cart - Number = '123' 
UNION SELECT 
    l.id, l.c_locationNumber
FROM
    location l
        JOIN
    shipmentParts sp ON sp.bin - Cart - Number = l.bin - Cart - Number
WHERE
    (l.bin - Cart - Number IS NULL
        OR l.bin - Cart - Number = '')
```

Comment: i can't figure out what `l.bin - Cart - Number` is a number and if they a constants why add them at all?

Comment: bin-Cart is a product unique number that is defined in catalogue

Comment: please make a [mre] bin-cart isn't allowed as tabee name or column name

Comment: you can use binCartNumber instead